# Creating Array of Integers to store spaces in grid Java

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, grid, coordinates

I am currently making a program which optimizes the placement of houses on a grid to gain the most profit.

The area plan is on a grid - all house details (dimensions etc) are entered by a user.

All houses must be placed next to a road - the roads have already been added to the grid by the user.

I am currently struggling to write a function which checks if the grid has any available space left to add another house (the stopping condition for my optimization algorithm).

The available space won't be the empty squares on the grid, but the empty squares adjacent to the road.
(This road can go both horizontal and vertical)

The grid:

```
Coords[][] grid;
```

If a coordinate on the grid is a road:

```
grid[x][y].getRoad() == true
```

The following function finds all neighbouring squares of any coordinate:
(cols - number of columns in grid)
(rows - number of rows in grid)

```
public static Coords[] addNeighboursSquare(Coords coord, int x, int y, int cols, int rows)
{
   Coords[] neighbours = null;

   //right
   if (x < cols - 1)
   {
      neighbours[0] = AStarAlgorithm.grid[x + 1][y];
   }

   //left
   if (x > 0)
   {
      neighbours[1] = AStarAlgorithm.grid[x - 1][y];
   }

   //top
   if (y < rows - 1)
   {
      neighbours[2] = AStarAlgorithm.grid[x][y + 1];
   }

   //bottom
   if (y > 0)
   {
      neighbours[3] = AStarAlgorithm.grid[x][y - 1];
   }

   return neighbours;
}
```

How do I loop through all roads squares in the grid, and create an array of ints containing the size of all 'gaps' along the road?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question after almost 3 years, but I probably have a solution for you if it's still valid:

1. Build graph: Your grid (map) may be converted to graph, where nodes contains coordinates and type (**ROAD**, **GROUND**) and edges are adjacent coordinates.
2. Discover **AVAILABLE_SPACE** nodes: you can use **DFS** or **BFS** algorithms now (little modified for this issue) to traverse through **ROAD** and return true where there is still some space along side road or store those available spaces sizes and coordinates if needed. Nodes that are **AVAILABLE_SPACE** type will be the **GROUND** types and in the direct neighbourhood of **ROAD** nodes. Maybe another traverse through **AVAILABLE_SPACE** nodes may be needed here after discover them.